# Recreate samples from a kernel density estimate

Tags: python, scipy, data-science, kernel-density

I am using tSNE to investigate differences between 2 groups of high-dimensional data. I concatenate all the data, run tSNE while keeping track of indices of data belonging to each group. Then, I perform kernel density estimation on the 2 sets of tSNE results. Next, I evaluate the 2 KDEs over a regular grid and finally take the difference of that result.

The final difference data is a grid of points where areas of higher density in group 1 are positive values and areas of higher density in group 2 are negative values.

What I would like to do is to create 2 new models from the negative and positive regions and sample new points from each. I need to generate samples from a density plot. How can I "reverse" the process of generating a density plot from data points?

Here's the relevant extract of code that gives me the difference plot, along with an example of the plot.

```
kde1 = gaussian_kde(
    np.vstack(
        [
            tsne_results1[:, 0],
            tsne_results1[:, 1]
        ]
    )
)
kde2 = gaussian_kde(
    np.vstack(
        [
            tsne_results2[:, 0],
            tsne_results2[:, 1]
        ]
    )
)

# evaluate on a regular grid
xgrid = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 250)
ygrid = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, 250)
Xgrid, Ygrid = np.meshgrid(xgrid, ygrid)
xy_grid = np.vstack([Xgrid.ravel(), Ygrid.ravel()])

z1 = kde1.evaluate(xy_grid)
z2 = kde2.evaluate(xy_grid)

z = z2 - z1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just after the [`resample`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.resample.html#scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.resample) method of your `kde`s., e.g:

```
kde1.resample(10)
```

will draw 10 samples from the KDE.  the function name is somewhat unfortunate, but it's pretty similar to `rvs` from `scipy.stats` distributions